# Javascript, parsing multiple values in a variable

Tags: javascript, var

I have a working html form (in laravel) that is using a javascript call to employe Ajax.

Right now I'm using console log to make sure my click event shows the variables which it does.

However, because of how my values are below, I get multiple values in one variable and I'm wondering if there's a way to parse them into their own.

For example, in my form I have multiple values sharing table cells:

```
<form id="saveLineup">
@foreach($lists as $list)

  <tr style="text-align:center;">
      <td id="groupNumber">{{$list['product']}} - {{$list['product_NAME']}}</td>
      <td id="detailColor">{{$list['detail']}}/{{$list['COLOR']}} - {{$list['description']}}</td>
      <td id="category">{{$list['CATEGORY']}}</td>
      <td><input id="addToLineup"> type="checkbox" <?php if ($list['LINE_UP'] == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>></td>
  </tr>  

@endforeach
</form>
```

But when I log my variables I get

```
category: "categoryOne" //which is correct
detailColor: "123/Blue - Description"
productNumber: 123 - productOne
```

What I'd like to do is parse those and have it all as separate values like so:

```
category:"categoryOne"
detail: "123"
color: "Blue"
productNumber: "123"
productDescription: "productOne"
```

Is there a way to do that within my JS?

```
$("#addToLineup").click(function (e) {

  var productNumber = document.getElementById("productNumber").innerHTML = productNumber;
  var detailColor = document.getElementById("detailColor").innerHTML = detailColor;
  var category = document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = category;

  updatedata.productNumber = productNumber;
  updatedata.detailColor = detailColor;
  updatedata.category = category;

  $.ajax({
    url: "/test/addToLineup",
    data: updatedata,
    _token: phpVariables.csrfToken,
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function () {
      showLoading(element);
    },
    success: function (data) {
      location.reload();
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the simplest way is splitting your variables like this:

```js
var detailColor = "123/Blue - Description";
var productNumber = "123 - productOne";

var first = detailColor.split(' - ');
var just_color = first[0].split('\/');
var detail = just_color[0];
var color = just_color[1];

var second = productNumber.split(' - ');
var product_number = second[0];
var product_description = second[1];

console.log(detail , color, product_number, product_description);
```

Comment: Thank you, and I also just realized: I'm building this within a php foreach loop so only my first checkbox works and logs only the first element. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel... try to delete the @endforeach

Comment: Not so much laravel, I just didn't know if I should account for that in JS since there can only be one ID

Comment: as far as I'm understanding your needs, you want to make this dynamic and with more elements, so I think you should try another approach, like this you'll have to manipulate everything within javascript before you call the ajax with is no good